# please explain the need of power 2 in variance => stdev

Tags: statistics, variance, standard-deviation

My question comes out of curiosity, and not enough knowledge.

I'm asking about the measurement of dispersion.

We know **stdev** is the square root of **variance**, which is in turn the mean of the squared distance of each observation to the mean of observations.

Is there a reason to prefer squaring for variance and rooting for stdev, over something more simplistic, in the spirit of :-

$$mydispersion = \frac {\sum_{i=0}^n abs(N_i - \mu)}{n}$$
$$where$$
$$\mu = \frac {\sum_{i=0}^n N_i}{n}$$

It was even interesting to build the MathJax formulae.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4709270/whats-the-significance-of-mean-squared-error-why-not-something-else/4709289#4709289 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63238/why-do-we-use-a-least-squares-fit/ or https://thestatsguy.rbind.io/post/2020/12/26/the-intuition-behind-averaging/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3392170/linear-fit-why-do-we-minimize-the-variance-and-not-the-sum-of-all-deviations?noredirect=1&lq=1 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967883/why-get-the-sum-of-squares-instead-of-the-sum-of-absolute-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: there is no "need" ...   measuring [Mean Absolute Deviation ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) as you propose is completely standard.  The best argument  for preferring the usual variance is that it plays a unique roll in the Central Limit Theorem.  Other arguments include analytic simplicity (the absolute value function lacks a derivative at $0$ and that complicates computations).

Comment: thank you very much @MatthewTowers

Comment: thank you very much @lulu